# Iterate through array of JSON objects in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Hi I have the following looking dataset:

```
[
    { date:"somedatehere", series1:"series1Value", series2:"series2Value" ..., seriesX:"seriesXValue"}, 
    { date:"anotherDateHere", series1:"anotherseries1Value", series2:"anotherseries2Value"...,seriesX:"anotherseriesXValue"},...
]
```

I'd like to loop through this in coffeescript and extract arrays such that I would have an array of `dates` (comprised of `somedatehere`, `anotherDateHere`, etc), `series1` values, `series2` values, `seriesX` values, etc.

Preferrably all of these arrays would go in order such that `dates[0] === somedatehere` and `series1[0] === series1Value` and `series2[0] === series2Value` and `seriesX[1] === anotherseriesXValue` etc.

Is there an easy way to go about doing this in coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dates = (obj.date for obj in my_array)
series1 = (obj.series for obj in my_array)
```

in case you have a lot of series and don't want to manually enumerate them:

```
types = (k for k, v of my_array[0])
result = {}
result[type] =  (obj[type] for obj in my_array) for type in types
```

Will give you

```
my_array = [{date: 1, x: 2}, {date: 123, x: 2134}]

result = {
  date: [ 1, 123 ],
  x: [ 2, 2134 ]
}
```